# Size Limit of Android Application that can be installed as APK

Tags: android, apk, size, android-file, android-install-apk

I am currently on an Android project which contains Videos/Audios and many Images. All these media files are in res/drawable or res/raw or in the assets directory of android project. When I build APK its size reached 300MBs and I haven't complete 50% of the project yet. Although project will not be uploaded on Google Play Store It will be installed  as it is. I am concern about the size of APK it will reach. Can you tell me what is the size limit of the APK that can be installed on an Android device. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no size limit, but Google play has a limit of 150mb and .aab files that exceed this limit cannot be uploaded as a normal build instead you have to use feature delivery.

You say that you are not going to upload to playstore; still 300mb is huge and cannot be justified.

1. Use code obfuscation techniques to remove unwanted code and resources.
2. Avoid hardcoding / adding huge resource files with the package. i.e., images and videos. Instead, if possible, make them load from a backend like Firestore.
3. Avoid usage of libraries even for menial tasks ( if you are doing that )

In conclusion, 300 mb is huge. Man, bring it down below 100 mb at least.

Comment: The application I am developing is for remote area and internet availability is nearly zero according to client. It is an education related application which tell people how to read and write. so all they want to have an apk which contain all data in like videos and audios and images. that is why its size is increasing. and i am concern about its size.

Comment: Oh. Anyway try code obfuscation at least to reduce size a bit. Congrats on the app btw.